# How is == in Character defined?

Tags: swift, unicode, equatable, grapheme-cluster

I see that "é" (`"\u{E9}"`, 1 code point), and "e" + acute (`"\u{65}\u{301}"`, 2 code points) are equal, which is great.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/2430739) of `==` for `Character` is inherited from `Equatable` and does not explain its rules. On the other hand, I have looked around [Annex #29](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) without luck. Does Swift implement its own logic?

In either case, how is character equality determined in Swift?

Comment: I think the answer to your unasked question is, "you need to manually normalize the two characters first".

Answer (score 2):

Since `Swift` is an open-source language, you can check the implementation of built-in methods on GitHub.

You can find the equality operator of `Character` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Character.swift#L217).

```
extension Character: Equatable {
  @inlinable @inline(__always)
  @_effects(readonly)
  public static func == (lhs: Character, rhs: Character) -> Bool {
    return lhs._str == rhs._str
  }
}
```

As you can see, internally, `Character` can be initialised from a `String` and the `==` operator for `Character` uses that internal `String` property to compare two `Character`s.

```
@frozen
public struct Character {
  @usableFromInline
  internal var _str: String

  @inlinable @inline(__always)
  internal init(unchecked str: String) {
    self._str = str
    _invariantCheck()
  }
}
```

You can find the implementation of `==` for `String` in [StringComparable.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5815468ebbd46900840f584989866f1b580035b6/stdlib/public/core/StringComparable.swift)

Comment: I had no idea it was open source! I am just starting to learn Swift, so I cannot follow everything. That file you linked is only a facade, you need to go downwards to follow different related code that performs special-cases and finally fallback to the actual generic algorithm.

I have not been able to reach the absolute boundary of the code, but according to a good deal of names, it looks like probably at least the most generic logic is delegated to the ICU C library.